# Add value for each year in python list

Tags: python

Given a list of [yyy,m,value], I need to add all the values corresponding to a single year. So that,

```
A = [
[['2008', '3', '5'],['2008', '4', '35'],['2013', '3', '71']],
[['2008', '6', '2'],['2008', '7', '2'],['2008', '8', '4'],['2013', '3', '128']]
]
```

becomes

```
A = [
[['2008', '40'],['2013','71']],
[['2008', '8'],['2013','128']]
]
```

What are the best possible ways? Thanks.

Comment: Your actual question appears to have nothing to do with the title.

Comment: sorry..that was a mistake. corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

b = []

for line in A:
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for entry in line:
        d[entry[0]] += int(entry[2])
    b.append([(k,str(v)) for k,v in sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: int(x[0]))])
```

gives

```
b
Out[71]: [[('2008', '40'), ('2013', '71')], [('2008', '8'), ('2013', '128')]]
```

Comment: Desired result was lists rather than tuples (though tuples are a better choice semantically).  Changing the innermost brackets of the `append` should do the trick:  `[k,str(v)]`

Comment: @MarkReed yes, if that matters the change is trivial as you say.  I imagine it doesn't matter.

Comment: If the order of the lists/tuples matter, you should sort the values in the temporary dict before appending to b. The order of the defaultdict or dict may be surprising.

Comment: @drewk noted, updated.

Comment: Since a four digit year is a reasonable subset of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) there is no need to convert the ASCII year to an int. All 4 digit years sort correctly lexicographically. Unless you are preparing for the dreaded Y10K issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could be explicit and use some simple loops like so:

```
A = [[['2008', '3', '5'],['2008', '4', '35'],['2013', '3', '71']],
[['2008', '6', '2'],['2008', '7', '2'],['2008', '8', '4'],['2013', '3', '128']]    ]

l,B,k=[],[],0

for x in A:
    for y in x:
        l.append(y[0])
    for z in set(l):
        for y in x:
             if y[0] == z:
                k += int(y[2])
        B.append([z,k])
        k=0
print B
```

This gives the expected:

```
>>>B
[['2008', 40], ['2013', 71], ['2008', 8], ['2013', 128]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
for i,li in enumerate(A):
    d={}
    for sli in li:
        year=sli[0]
        d.setdefault(year,0)
        d[year]+=int(sli[-1])

    A[i]=[[k,str(d[k])] for k in sorted(d.keys())]
```

A's values are replaced in place:

```
>>> A
[[['2008', '40'], ['2013', '71']], [['2008', '8'], ['2013', '128']]]
```